# how to run Cmd command(chkdsk) on selected drive in a dataGridView

Tags: visual-studio, button, datagridview, cmd

I am building a program in visual-studio to check and fix drive using the cmd chkdsk command
I have been able to display the list of drive available is a dataGridview
I want to run chkdsk command on any selected drive(by the user)  please how do I achieve that successfully. Furthermore I want the process and result of the chkdsk to be displayed on a  textbox.
problem is the drives are displaying but when one is select and i click on the button fix is dose not execute(i.e fix the drive and show result&process in the textbox)  Any help/code/suggestion will b appreciated, please note this is note a console application. My code are on is posted here as requested. i added the subs were i feel the problem could be from. , but if you want me to add more of my other subs i will.

```
 Public Class Form2
        Private binder As New BindingSource
        Private drives As New BindingList(Of DriveInfo)
        Private psi As ProcessStartInfo
        Private cmd As Process
        Private Delegate Sub invokeWithString(ByVal text As String)
        Dim BackgrounndWorker1 As New BackgroundWorker
    Private Shadows Sub OnClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnfix.Click
            If TypeOf sender Is Button Then
                Dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
                btn.Enabled = False
                If btn.Equals(btnfix) Then
                    Ddrives.Enabled = False
                    pgb.Visible = True
                    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(New List(Of DriveInfo)(From drive As DriveInfo In cldrive.CheckedItems Select drive))

                End If
            End If
        End Sub
Private Sub OnDoWOrk(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        If TypeOf sender Is BackgroundWorker Then
            Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)
            If e.Argument IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf e.Argument Is IEnumerable(Of DriveInfo) Then
                Dim drives As IEnumerable(Of DriveInfo) = DirectCast(e.Argument, IEnumerable(Of DriveInfo))
                For Each drive As DriveInfo In drives
                    Try
                        cmd.Kill()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try
                    TextBox1.Text = ""
                    psi = New ProcessStartInfo("Chkdsk /f")
                    Dim systemcoding As System.Text.Encoding =
                       System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
                    With psi
                        .UseShellExecute = False
                        .RedirectStandardError = True
                        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
                        .RedirectStandardInput = True
                        .CreateNoWindow = True
                        .StandardOutputEncoding = systemcoding
                        .StandardErrorEncoding = systemcoding
                    End With
                    cmd = New Process With {.StartInfo = psi, .EnableRaisingEvents = True}
                    AddHandler cmd.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Async_data_received
                    AddHandler cmd.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf Async_data_received
                    Try
                        cmd.Start()
                        cmd.BeginOutputReadLine()
                        cmd.BeginErrorReadLine()
                    Catch ex As System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
                    End Try
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Async_data_received(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        Me.Invoke(New invokeWithString(AddressOf Sync_output), e.Data)
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm really curious why you spent so much time taking screen shots and including them in your post instead of just including the code itself (which you will now need to do anyway).  Please remove the images and include the actual code in the question, and please make sure it's formatted properly.  If you need assistance with that, review the [help] documentation.

Comment: Please put code into your question as *text* (images are too hard to read).

Comment: OK thank I will put the code now

Comment: @jesse -- also, make sure you only include relevant code.  If you can, provide a [mcve].

Comment: i have added the some code pls reply

Comment: Checking the e.Error property in your RunWorkerCompleted event handler is not optional.  Only decent way to discover that your DoWork event handler bombed, it cannot update UI.  Using a BackgroundWorker is entirely unnecessary, so get ahead by not using one.

Comment: Okk then I how I get the selected item(drive) on the dateGridView to b recognized as a drive and treated as such. There by exciting the chkdsk command??